# Rendering an image as a node in Three.js with SVGRenderer (or otherwise rendering spheres)

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js, webgl

I have a `<circle>` element in an SVG document, to which I apply a `<radialGradient>` to give the illusion of it being a sphere:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="sphere_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="640px" height="640px" viewBox="0 0 640 640" enable-background="new 0 0 640 640" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="sphere_gradient" cx="292.3262" cy="287.4077" r="249.2454" fx="147.7949" fy="274.5532" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0729 0 0 1.0729 -23.3359 -23.3359)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop id="sphere_gradient_0" offset="0" style="stop-color:#F37D7F"/>
            <stop id="sphere_gradient_1" offset="0.4847" style="stop-color:#ED1F24"/>
            <stop id="sphere_gradient_2" offset="1" style="stop-color:#7E1416"/>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle fill="url(#sphere_gradient)" cx="320" cy="320" r="320"/>
</svg>
```

It looks something like this:

[image: red sphere]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLo97a6g/)

I can render this in a three.js `WebGLRenderer` container by using [Gabe Lerner's `canvg` library](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg):

```
/* sphere_asset is a div containing the svg element */
var red_svg_html = new String($('#sphere_asset').html()); 
var red_svg_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvg(red_svg_canvas, red_svg_html);
var red_svg_texture = new THREE.Texture(red_svg_canvas);
var red_particles = new THREE.Geometry();
var red_particle_material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({ 
    map: red_svg_texture, 
    transparent: true, 
    size: 0.15, 
    alphaTest: 0.10 
});
var red_particle_count = 25;
for (var p = 0; p < red_particle_count; p++) {
    var pX = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5),
        pY = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5),
        pZ = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5),
        red_particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);
    red_particles.vertices.push(red_particle);
}
var red_particle_system = new THREE.PointCloud(red_particles, red_particle_material);
scene.add(red_particle_system);
```

So far, so good. I can even programmatically modify the gradient and render different categories of particles:

[image: spheres]

What I would like to do is now switch over from `WebGLRenderer` to using an `SVGRenderer`, so that I can allow the end user to set the desired orientation and then export a vector image (SVG, or converted to PDF on the back end) that can be used for publication-quality work.

Using the [SVG sandbox example](http://threejs.org/examples/#svg_sandbox) from three.js as the basis for experimentation, I have tried a couple different techniques and have not had much luck. I'm hoping someone with experience with three.js may have some suggestions.

My first attempt was to use `canvg` to render the SVG into a PNG image, and then apply that to an `<image>` node:

```
var red_svg_html = new String($('#sphere_asset').html());
var red_svg_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvg(red_svg_canvas, red_svg_html);
var red_png_data = red_svg_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var red_node = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
red_node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', red_png_data);
red_node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'height', '10');
red_node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'width', '10');
var red_particle_count = 25;
for (var i = 0; i < red_particle_count; i++) {
    var object = new THREE.SVGObject(red_node.cloneNode());
    object.position.x = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5);
    object.position.y = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5);
    object.position.z = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5);
    scene.add(object);
}
```

No nodes show up in my viewbox.

The next thing I tried was a `THREE.Sprite` object, using `canvg` and `THREE.Texture` routines:

```
var red_svg_html = new String($('#sphere_asset').html());
var red_svg_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvg(red_svg_canvas, red_svg_html);
var red_svg_texture = new THREE.Texture(red_svg_canvas);
red_svg_texture.needsUpdate = true;
var red_sprite = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(red_png_data);
var red_particle_count = 25;
for (var p = 0; p < red_particle_count; p++) {
    var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { 
        map: red_svg_texture, 
        transparent: true, 
        size: 0.15, 
        alphaTest: 0.10 
    });
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );
    sprite.position.x = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5),
    sprite.position.y = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5),
    sprite.position.z = 0.9 * (Math.random() - 0.5),
    sprite.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    scene.add(sprite);
}
```

This was slightly better, in that I get white, opaque boxes where the spheres would otherwise appear in the rendered viewbox.

A third attempt was made to create an `<svg>` to nest within the parent SVG node, which contains a reference-able `<radialGradient>` with the id `#sphere_gradient`:

```
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'svg');
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'version', '1.1');
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '0px');
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '0px');
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '640px');
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '640px');
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '0 0 640 640');
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'enable-background', 'new 0 0 640 640');

var defs = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "defs");
var radialGradient = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "radialGradient");
radialGradient.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "sphere_gradient");
radialGradient.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", "292.3262");
radialGradient.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", "287.4077");
radialGradient.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "249.2454");
radialGradient.setAttributeNS(null, "fx", "147.7949");
radialGradient.setAttributeNS(null, "fy", "274.5532");
radialGradient.setAttributeNS(null, "gradientTransform", "matrix(1.0729 0 0 1.0729 -23.3359 -23.3359)");
radialGradient.setAttributeNS(null, "gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");

var stop0 = document.createElementNS(null, "stop");
stop0.setAttributeNS(null, "offset", "0");
stop0.setAttributeNS(null, "stop-color", "#f37d7f");
radialGradient.appendChild(stop0);

var stop1 = document.createElementNS(null, "stop");
stop1.setAttributeNS(null, "offset", "0.4847");
stop1.setAttributeNS(null, "stop-color", "#ed1f24");
radialGradient.appendChild(stop1);

var stop2 = document.createElementNS(null, "stop");
stop2.setAttributeNS(null, "offset", "1");
stop2.setAttributeNS(null, "stop-color", "#7e1416");
radialGradient.appendChild(stop2);

defs.appendChild(radialGradient);

svg.appendChild(defs);

var red_circle = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "circle")
red_circle.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#sphere_gradient)');
red_circle.setAttribute('r', '320');
red_circle.setAttribute('cx', '320');
red_circle.setAttribute('cy', '320');
svg.appendChild(red_circle);

var red_particle_count = 25;
for (var i = 0; i < red_particle_count; i++) {
    var object = new THREE.SVGObject(svg.cloneNode(true));
    object.position.x = 0.85 * (Math.random() - 0.5);
    object.position.y = 0.85 * (Math.random() - 0.5);
    object.position.z = 0.85 * (Math.random() - 0.5);
    scene.add(object);
}
```

No nodes are rendered. Adjustments of the `<circle>` element's `r`, `cx` or `cy` do not change the end result.

Interestingly, if I change the `fill` attribute from `url(#sphere_gradient)` to `red`, I get a large circle mostly rendered outside my viewbox, which is not attached to the scene (it does not rotate with other elements in my parent scene, like the sides of a cube).

Is there a (working and performant) way to draw spheres or rounded, sphere-like particles in space using a `SVGRenderer` in three.js?

Answer (score 2):

Most attributes in SVG are in the null namespace so

```
red_node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'height', '10');
red_node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'width', '10');
```

is correctly written as

```
red_node.setAttribute('height', '10');
red_node.setAttribute('width', '10');
```

FWIW

```
red_node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', red_png_data);
```

should ideally be written as

```
red_node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', red_png_data);
```

although in this case your original form will work in most UAs.

In the final example the stop elements must be in the SVG namespace i.e.

```
var stop0 = document.createElementNS(null, "stop");
```

should be

```
var stop0 = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "stop");
```

A gradient without stops is not drawn at all so that's why you don't see anything till you change the fill to red.

SVG has a painters model. Things are drawn in the order they occur in the file. If you want something to go on top of something else you need to place it later in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Modification of the `href` attribute to `xlink:href` did not change the end result (*i.e.*, none of the nodes are rendered, still).

Comment: Okay, thanks — the namespace change helps in that a gradient is now applied! 

However, it looks like the transform applied to this nested `<svg>` element does not get computed into the scene, so the `<circle>` element contained within stays fixed to its location, even if a transform is applied to its parent `<svg>`.

Comment: I have had some success moving the `<defs>` group into the `SVGRenderer` code so that it is part of the root-most `<svg>`, but I get rendering problems where `<circle>` elements are not drawn "in order", which breaks the illusion of depth.

Specifically, a `<circle>` element that is closer to the camera is drawn first, before another element that is further away from the camera.

The result is that the element that is closer to the camera (and which should be in the foreground) is instead rendered underneath the element further away. Rotating the scene breaks the illusion of depth.

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt, if you add the [snap svg](http://snapsvg.io/docs/) library, you could get the svg element(s) from canvg and wrap it into snap structure (as a paper for snap) and then use the paper.toString() method to produce the svg code for your svg File.

```
var paper = Snap("#... ");        //this wraps the svg element from the canvg onto snap structure 
console.log( paper.toString());   // this gives you the svg code!
```

Edit: Or you could use [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html) to convert canvas to svg:

```
var svg = canvas.toSVG();
```

Or you could use canvas2svg library.

Comment: I already have the SVG. I would be converting from SVG to PNG to SVG again?

Comment: You already have your initial svg , not the updated one.Here is the steps I think can help you: You have an svg then you add that to a canvas to add extra to it, then from canvas you need to get the updated svg. Your last part is not functioning to get the updated svg. Isn't that what you want to do to simplify your process?!

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "updated". The SVG is self-contained; I'm already bringing it in as a string: `var red_svg_html = new String($('#sphere_asset').html());`

Comment: BY updated svg I mean the svg that you want your users be exporting."What I would like to do is now switch over from WebGLRenderer to using an SVGRenderer, so that I can allow the end user to set the desired orientation and then export a vector image ..." And using SVGRenderer you CAN NOT do what you want.it is limited. So you need to be using the webGLrenderer and then use one of the libraries I mentioned, to export the desired orientation of your canvas to an svg.

Comment: Can you put up your third approach in a jsbin, I think I have the answer for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to add to your SVGRenerer.js to fix your problem with rendering Particles:

```
function renderParticle( v1, element, material, scene ) {


        _svgNode = getCircleNode( _circleCount++ );
        _svgNode.setAttribute( 'cx', v1.x );
        _svgNode.setAttribute( 'cy', v1.y );
        _svgNode.setAttribute( 'r', element.scale.x * _svgWidthHalf );

        if ( material instanceof THREE.ParticleCircleMaterial ) {

            if ( _enableLighting ) {

                _color.r = _ambientLight.r + _directionalLights.r + _pointLights.r;
                _color.g = _ambientLight.g + _directionalLights.g + _pointLights.g;
                _color.b = _ambientLight.b + _directionalLights.b + _pointLights.b;

                _color.r = material.color.r * _color.r;
                _color.g = material.color.g * _color.g;
                _color.b = material.color.b * _color.b;

                _color.updateStyleString();

            } else {

                _color = material.color;

            }

            _svgNode.setAttribute( 'style', 'fill: ' + _color.__styleString );

        }

        _svg.appendChild( _svgNode );


    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in a previous comment, there are two problems I had with customizing the SVGRenderer: 1. I cannot easily assign a programmatically-generated radial gradient, and so I am stuck with whatever gradient I create. 2. The end result does not render a correct 3D view, in that elements closer to the camera are not rendered on top of elements that are further away from the camera, and are not scaled correctly. Rotating the particles shows how this 'breaks'. It is not clear how to reorder `<circle>` elements to render a correct 3D scene. Both of these problems are deal-breakers.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the SVGRender.js file you are using right now?

Comment: OK, please use this file instead and let me know if it works: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/140225334/SVGRenderer.js

Comment: Its use results in the following error on line 17: `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new THREE.Rectangle()')`

Comment: Ok, can you share your setup in a jsfiddle or jsbin or email it to me to check it for you.

Comment: Dependencies aren't shared from CDNs and so will not load from Jsfiddle. It looks like the problem is with the JS file you posted, in any case.

Comment: I can find the dependencies and host them in my dropbox, if that is the reason. I know  that the problem is likely with the js file I hosted, I just want to try different options to see what works.