# How to load SVG file into SVGRenderer in three.js

Tags: svg, three.js

I'm trying to use `SVGRenderer` in three.js (http://threejs.org/examples/#svg_sandbox). The example shows you how to make an SVG element (a circle) on the fly. I want to import an SVG file that I already have in my computer. How would I do that?

The createElementNS command doesn't seem to support importing SVG files?

I essentially want my `image.svg` to be displayed on a three.js scene.

Comment: can't you load it as an image an use it as a texture?

Comment: I'd like to interact with the svg elements. E..g. Animate them or change colors etc.

Comment: I can't find `svgRenderer` in the docs but there is an [`svgLoader`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/SVGLoader) that will parse an external svg file

Comment: SVGLoader returns an SVGDocument. I tried passing that to the SVGRenderer and it errors out. I somehow need to convert that SVGDocument into an element?

Comment: Then try SVGDocument.documentElement

Comment: `var svgManager = new THREE.SVGLoader();

 var url = '/svg/graph.svg';

 svgManager.load ( 
  url, svg_loading_done_callback, function(){console.log("Loading SVG...");}, function(){console.log("Error loading SVG!");} 

 );

  var object = new THREE.SVGObject( svgObject.documentElement.cloneNode() );
`

Gives me error saying "svgObject.documentElement" is undefined.

Comment: I just tried and the object passed into the load callback of the `SVGLoader` constructor is actually an svgElement. So you can pass it directly into the `SVGObject` constructor : `function svg_loading_done_callback(svgObject){ var object = new THREE.SVGObject( svgObject); doSomethingWith(object)}`

Comment: I tried doing that. When I do, `scene.add (object)`, SVGRenderer gives me an error saying: `node.attribute is not a function. (line 220: SVGRenderer.js)`. If you got it to work and actually display an SVG in a three.js scene, could you please share the code?

Comment: Perhaps use an `$.ajax` call (via jQuery or similar) and take a look at the first answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27642270/19410

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [THREE.SVGLoader()](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/SVGLoader) Library to achieve it :

```js
var svgManager = new THREE.LegacySVGLoader();
var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg';

function svg_loading_done_callback(doc) {
  init(new THREE.SVGObject(doc));
  animate();
};

svgManager.load(url,
  svg_loading_done_callback,
  function() {
    console.log("Loading SVG...");
  },
  function() {
    console.log("Error loading SVG!");
  });

var camera, scene, renderer;

function init(svgObject) {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000);
  camera.position.z = 1500;

  svgObject.position.x = Math.random() * innerWidth;
  svgObject.position.y = 200;
  svgObject.position.z = Math.random() * 10000 - 5000;
  svgObject.scale.x = svgObject.scale.y = svgObject.scale.z = 0.01;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.add(svgObject);

  var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x80ffff);
  scene.add(ambient);
  var directional = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffff00);
  directional.position.set(-1, 0.5, 0);
  scene.add(directional);
  renderer = new THREE.SVGRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0xf0f0f0);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight - 5);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  var time = Date.now() * 0.0002;
  camera.position.x = Math.sin(time) * 200;
  camera.position.z = Math.cos(time) * 200;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/SVGLoader.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * @name LegacySVGLoader
   * @author mrdoob / http://mrdoob.com/
   * @author zz85 / http://joshuakoo.com/
   * @see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14387
   */

  THREE.LegacySVGLoader = function(manager) {

    this.manager = (manager !== undefined) ? manager : THREE.DefaultLoadingManager;

  };

  THREE.LegacySVGLoader.prototype = {

    constructor: THREE.LegacySVGLoader,

    load: function(url, onLoad, onProgress, onError) {

      var scope = this;

      var parser = new DOMParser();

      var loader = new THREE.FileLoader(scope.manager);
      loader.load(url, function(svgString) {

        var doc = parser.parseFromString(svgString, 'image/svg+xml'); // application/xml

        onLoad(doc.documentElement);

      }, onProgress, onError);

    }

  };
</script>
```

Comment: It works...sigh. It was my SVGLoader.js. I downloaded it off the github of three.js, and once I replaced the that with the line you provided directly from the website, it worked. Thanks a lot, you're the best.

Comment: I have a question you might help me with: How would I access a sub child of this svg object through three.js? For example, if I wanted to change NewTux's beak color, say `#path136`, how do I select that child element? I can't seem to use the standard Jquery methods..

Comment: So I tried doing this:
` var pathobj = svgObject.node.getElementById("path136");`
` pathobj.setAttribute ('opacity', 0);`
And it seems to work. But is this actually being handled by the SVGRenderer through three.js or not?
Do you think this is the right way to go?

Comment: the loaded svg document is not appended to the DOM. To access it you have to keep a reference of its id or to give it a name then use `scene.getObjectById(savedId).node` or `scene.getObjectByName(setName).node`. It seems that SVGRenderer updates the svg image on each draw, so you can actually modify the svg's sub-elements on the flow and it will be updated directly.

Comment: SVGLoader has changed, it provides paths now which is an array instead of doc as shown in the example. SVGObject is no longer available. The jsfiddle also doesn't work. 
Anyway, if the SVG has image URLs embedded, then SVGLoader doesn't work and also gives no errors. Anybody has any suggestions?

Comment: things are changed in three.js so this link could help: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14387

Comment: @pera thanks a lot for the heads-up and the link. Applied it in the snippet, I saw lifetimeLearner007's message and then forgot about it before I could have a look at it. So thanks again.

Comment: @lifetimeLearner007 sorry I didn't caught your message earlier, pera provided the workaround you needed.

Comment: @Kaiido this legacy loader is not quite working as expected. I can not change svgObject.position. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @pera I also faced it while editing the answer and no, I don't know how to fix it yet. I have to admit I didn't gone back to this since last 3 years and I'm kind of rusted. If I get some time I'll try to look back into it.

Comment: I asked for example from three.js github issue and I got working example here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/15528

Comment: @Kaiido, As I pointed out it doesn't work if SVG has image URLs embedded in it. I get svg dynamically which I want to convert to threejs material/texture, add it to the geometry and then render. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is current answer from latest three.js lib:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=svg#webgl_loader_svg

but this code loads svg into geometry mesh, so it is not a DOM element, it zooms out just like any other 3d object. Its like a billboard in 3d scene. If someone needs this kind of behavior then its fine.

If you want to load SVG to be DOM element, to have it float over 3D scene, to be able to add mouse click and hover events... I asked for example and here it is:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/15528

Comment: thank you for your reply! Do you happen to know if SVG-embedded style (in particular the animation) works using SVGLoader and SVGRenderer? It's not a native SVG animation (not sure if that one is supported). Or should I perhaps ask a separate question?