# Trouble rendering a 2D SVG in Three.js & WebGL

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, three.js, webgl

I have a ThreeJS Scene (below, or [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/coloradical/pen/eYNporL)) with some objects in it - one is a Mesh object of a cat, one is a cube, and now, I'm trying to render [a 2D SVG illustration](https://gist.github.com/coloradical/b11896f51f140d7399c246117b4256af) I made. I want to put the SVG illustration in the scene in between the cat image and the cube, displayed the same way the cat image appears (upright, and 2D).

It has taken me days to figure out how to render my own SVG, I find the documentation and examples on ThreeJs.org for SVGRenderer and SVGLoader extremely cumbersome and hard to pick apply to my own image (I'm a novice). The closest I've come to rendering my SVG is using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140342/how-to-load-svg-file-into-svgrenderer-in-three-js) SO thread that uses a [LegacySVG](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14387) Loader. Problem is, I'm completely lost on how to render this code onto a canvas versus a DOM, and it appears this LegacySVG Loader was a solution to a bug which makes it extremely hard to find resources.

So, essentially, I have rendered an SVG in [an individual CodePen](https://codepen.io/coloradical/pen/ExjVJrz) using the above resources and now I am lost on how to render it onto the same scene as my cube and cat image. Is it possible to use LegacySVG to render onto a canvas? Or, is there a simpler way to get my SVG onto the same canvas as the other objects?

```js
let renderer;
let camera;
//let controls;

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(54, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    canvas: document.getElementById("viewport")
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xfefefe));
// document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.x = 1;
camera.position.y = 1;
camera.position.z = 15;





let light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(light);

let gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
scene.add(gridHelper);

// example code

const geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
});
const topBox = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
scene.add(topBox);

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

// Load an image file into a custom material
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  map: loader.load('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80')
});

// create a plane geometry for the image with a width of 10
// and a height that preserves the image's aspect ratio
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 1.5);

// combine our image geometry and material into a mesh
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

// set the position of the image mesh in the x,y,z dimensions
mesh.position.set(0,0,5);

// add the image to the scene
scene.add(mesh); 



let animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    //controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
//////////////////
animate();

function updateCamera(ev) {
  
 camera.position.z = 15 - window.scrollY / 250.0;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", updateCamera);
```

```css
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
  
}

canvas {
 position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

#threeD {
    position: fixed;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
    
}
.page-wrapper {
 padding: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 
  height: 4000vh;
}



#container {
 height: 500vh;
 position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/src/loaders/LoadingManager.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.102.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r68/examples/js/loaders/SVGLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index1.css" />

    
    <body>
            <canvas id="viewport"></canvas>
         
                <div class="page-wrapper" >
                  <h1> scroll! </h1>

                
                  
                </div>

            
    </body>
   

 <script src="index1.js"></script>
    

</html>
```

Comment: Hard to understand plz post minimal required code for the shake of better understanding

Comment: unfortunately nothing about webGL is minimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you need to keep in mind.

1. [SVGRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/SVGRenderer) does not render the same things as [WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer).

   a. **SVGRenderer** takes items inside an `<svg>` element and applies transformations to its internal `<path>`, `<circle>`, `<rect>`, etc, elements. You can see the [svg_sandbox example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=svg#svg_sandbox). All SVG elements are 2D, but can give the impression of being 3D when rotated.

   b. **WebGLRenderer** draws onto a `<canvas>` element, and can render all kinds of true 3D geometry. If you want to draw an SVG in WebGL, you'll need to first convert the SVG file into a geometry that WebGL can understand by using [`THREE.SVGLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/SVGLoader). You can see how that's done in the [webgl_loader_svg example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=svg#webgl_loader_svg), (the source code is available by clicking on the `<>` button on the bottom right).
2. You cannot have `<svg>` elements co-existing in the same 3D space as WebGL elements in the `<canvas>`. If you want to add cubes and planes with cat images to the same space, I recommend you use the WebGLRenderer approach.
3. I noticed in your code snippet that you're using files from many different sources, and all kinds of Three.js revisions. Some files are `r102.1`, some are `r68`, and some are the latest, which is `r113`. You should stick to one revision to avoid conflicts when trying to get older files to work with newer ones. For example:

   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/r113/build/three.min.js
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/r113/examples/js/loaders/SVGLoader.js

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This clarification has helped me so much, I really appreciate it

Comment: Ultimately my goal is to just have a canvas with a bunch of 2D SVGs that I can scroll through. Do you think since they'll be stationary, that I should just use WebGLRenderer?

Comment: @MeganByers Not sure, depends on what you mean by "scrolling", and even then it could be a matter of opinion. You should ask that in a more open-ended discussion forum, like https://discourse.threejs.org/